# Stack Overflow etiquette for sharing files and resources

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, etiquette, rules

What are the rules/etiquette for giving files to other users that relate to a post. I have not seen any ability to add attachments to a post, but sometimes to give help, external files are needed.

I realize that taking a question/answer offline via email is very bad, and rightly so, but users may not always be able to put files and resources on the web where they can be accessed by everyone.

**So I ask the community:** What would be the best way to put up a file that is related to a post so that all users can benefit from it. Or, should it just be avoided all together?

Answer (score 11):

For large source-code snippets I use [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/). For file attachments I usually just post a zip file on my own domain.

Answer (score 8):

For sharing code snippets [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) is the standard usually and I really like [Mathbin](https://mathbin.net)*****  for when you want to share pretty-latex math equations.

There are also multi-upload services (such as [clonemyfile](https://clonemyfile.com)*****) that submit your single file to several services such as Rapidshare, Easyshare, etc.  These might be a good option because of the increase in redundancy.  I hate nothing more than getting to a forum post or thread to find the source links are dead.

---

**Notes**:

- [The link to Mathbin has been reported dead since June 2015; see this
  sample capture instead](https://web.archive.org/web/20081217073431/http://mathbin.net/). An alternative would be [mathb.in](http://mathb.in/) or [Quick Latex](https://quicklatex.com/).
- [The link to clonemyfile has been reported dead since December 2019;
  see this sample capture instead](https://web.archive.org/web/20081210055459/http://www.clonemyfile.com/). You may attempt to build one locally.

Comment: link to clonemyfile no longer works

Comment: link to mathbin no longer works

Comment: FileDropper does nothing. Seems to not be working.

Comment: @Pedro77 thanks, added to the notes. Their website is up and running, so it's not just dead, maybe only temporary issue.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like FileDropper from the other answer doesn't work anymore.

I ended up going with mega.io. It has been around for a while so it is less likely to disappear. There is a 20gb limit for free accounts.