# Revision sources are misleading at a glance

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list

On the **Revisions** page for a post, you have the option of viewing the **source**.  This feature takes you to a path ending in `/view-source`. My first impression of this feature was "Cool! I'm looking at the plain, unformatted text!"; the `textarea` input, if you will.

**But!** It is not only the source text. The `/view-source` page is a very simple HTML page which presents the source in a styled `pre` element.

The problem with this is that we end up with artificial line breaks (wrapping), as the source is constrained to a width of `650px` using the `white-space: pre-wrap` property. So, at a glance, it appears that the line breaks are part of the actual source.

Can we change this? I expect to view the source and nothing else when I click "source".

Example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/a6bacc34-0676-465e-9de7-d177eef2a03f/view-source

Comment: What you say is true, but I don't see the value in implementing a change to "true source."

Comment: Changing it to `whites-space: pre` means a lot of horizontal scrolling. I don't like horizontal scrolling.

Comment: It doesn't have to mean horizontal scrolling. Let's just "constrain" it to the entire page.