# How to deliver clean code to SO

Tags: support, code-formatting

Can anyone tell me how deliver clean code to SO when using the format as code option?

You can see my problem here. The code has a horizontal scrollbar, which is most annoying to the reader.

```
<!-- Simple multi image addon -->
                 <div id="fancy">
                  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="right">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" class="smallText">

<?php if (strlen($product_info['products_name']) > $max_title_length) {  $title = wordwrap(htmlspecialchars($product_info['products_name']), $max_title_length, '<br>');
         } else { $title = htmlspecialchars($product_info['products_name']); } 
$m_source = ''; $thumb = (class_exists('oscthumb') && CFG_MASTER_SWITCH == 'On'); if ($thumb) { preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/',htmlentities ( tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $product_info['products_image'],'','','','','',5), ENT_NOQUOTES), $image);  $m_source=str_replace('&amp;','&',$image[1]); }
  echo '<a  rel="image_group" title="'.$title.'" href="' . ($m_source ? $m_source : DIR_WS_IMAGES . $product_info['products_image']) . '" alt="' . $product_info['products_name'] . '" target="_blank">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $product_info['products_image'], $product_info['products_name'], SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH, SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT, 'hspace="5" vspace="5"', false, 5) . '<br /></a>'; 
               if(!$vertical_format) { echo ''; $row = 1; reset($products_image_array); foreach($products_image_array as $value) { 
                             if ($thumb) {      
                             $source = ''; preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/',htmlentities ( tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $value,'','','','','',5), ENT_NOQUOTES), $image);  $source=str_replace('&amp;','&',$image[1]); 
                             } 
                             echo '<a  rel="image_group" title="'.$title.'" href="' . ($source ? $source : DIR_WS_IMAGES . $value) . '" target="_blank">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $value, $product_info['products_name'], TINY_IMAGE_WIDTH, TINY_IMAGE_HEIGHT, 'hspace="5" vspace="5"') . '</a>'; 

                                ++$row; if ($row > $image_group) { echo '<br />'; $row = 1; } } } 
                                echo '</td>';
                             if($vertical_format) { echo '<td>'; $row = 1; reset($products_image_array); foreach($products_image_array as $value) { 
                             if ($thumb) {      
                             $source = ''; preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/',htmlentities ( tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $value,'','','','','',5), ENT_NOQUOTES), $image);  $source=str_replace('&amp;','&',$image[1]); 
                             } 
                             echo '<a  rel="image_group" title="'.$title.'" href="' . ($source ? $source : DIR_WS_IMAGES . $value) . '" target="_blank">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $value, $product_info['products_name'], TINY_IMAGE_WIDTH, TINY_IMAGE_HEIGHT, 'hspace="5" vspace="5"') . '<br />' . '</a>'; 

                                    ++$row; if ($row > $image_group) { echo '</td><td>'; $row = 1; } } echo '</td>'; } ?>


            </tr><?php  echo '<tr><td class="smallText">' . TEXT_CLICK_TO_ENLARGE . '</td></tr>'; ?>
          </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- EOF Simple multi image addon -->
```

Comment: You call that code "clean"?

Comment: @Ether no, he didn't, as said above.

Answer (score 11):

Well, the problem is that you've got enormously long lines.

Reformat them to whatever width it is that SO scrolls at.

Comment: Indeed, you even continue new statements after semicolons with no newline. That's not illegal, but it's certainly unusual, and I would say hard to read. Moving statements to their own lines would be an easy first step in reducing the horizontal scrollbar issue.

Comment: On second glance, this seems to be OSCommerce code. Sadly, the whole of that product looks this way.

Comment: the problem is he pasted too much code.

Comment: @Kev: That's certainly a lot of the problem. But you can have long lines without pasting too much code, too.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an answer by example. My strategy was simple: Indent consistently and add new lines after semicolons. That's all I did; I **intentionally did not even read the code at all**.

```
<!-- Simple multi image addon -->
<div id="fancy">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="right">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="smallText">

            <?php
            if (strlen($product_info['products_name']) > $max_title_length) {
                $title = wordwrap(htmlspecialchars($product_info['products_name']),
                    $max_title_length, '<br>');
            } else {
                $title = htmlspecialchars($product_info['products_name']);
            }

            $m_source = '';

            $thumb = (class_exists('oscthumb') && CFG_MASTER_SWITCH == 'On');

            if ($thumb) {
                preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/',htmlentities ( tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $product_info['products_image'],'','','','','',5), ENT_NOQUOTES), $image);

                $m_source=str_replace('&amp;','&',$image[1]);
            }

            echo '<a  rel="image_group" title="'.$title.'" href="' . ($m_source ? $m_source : DIR_WS_IMAGES . $product_info['products_image']) . '" alt="' . $product_info['products_name'] . '" target="_blank">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $product_info['products_image'], $product_info['products_name'], SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH, SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT, 'hspace="5" vspace="5"', false, 5) . '<br /></a>';

            if(!$vertical_format) {
                echo '';
                $row = 1;
                reset($products_image_array);
                    foreach($products_image_array as $value) {
                        if ($thumb) {
                            $source = '';
                            preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/',htmlentities ( tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $value,'','','','','',5), ENT_NOQUOTES), $image);
                            $source=str_replace('&amp;','&',$image[1]);
                        }
                        echo '<a  rel="image_group" title="'.$title.'" href="' . ($source ? $source : DIR_WS_IMAGES . $value) . '" target="_blank">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $value, $product_info['products_name'], TINY_IMAGE_WIDTH, TINY_IMAGE_HEIGHT, 'hspace="5" vspace="5"') . '</a>';

                        ++$row;

                        if ($row > $image_group) {
                            echo '<br />';
                            $row = 1;
                        }
                    }
                } 

                echo '</td>';

                if($vertical_format) {
                    echo '<td>';
                    $row = 1;
                    reset($products_image_array);

                    foreach($products_image_array as $value) {
                        if ($thumb) {
                            $source = '';
                            preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/',htmlentities ( tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $value,'','','','','',5), ENT_NOQUOTES), $image);  $source=str_replace('&amp;','&',$image[1]);
                        }

                        echo '<a  rel="image_group" title="'.$title.'" href="' . ($source ? $source : DIR_WS_IMAGES . $value) . '" target="_blank">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $value, $product_info['products_name'], TINY_IMAGE_WIDTH, TINY_IMAGE_HEIGHT, 'hspace="5" vspace="5"') . '<br />' . '</a>';

                        ++$row;

                        if ($row > $image_group) {
                            echo '</td><td>';
                            $row = 1;
                        }
                    }

                    echo '</td>';
                }
                ?>

        </tr>

        <?php
        echo '<tr><td class="smallText">' . TEXT_CLICK_TO_ENLARGE . '</td></tr>';
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- EOF Simple multi image addon -->
```

You'll notice that the scrollbars are still there. That's because some of your lines are long `echo` statements that I couldn't fix without reading and rewriting some code. Looking now, it seems that those lines contain embedded if statements and function calls. If you separate those sorts of things out into separate lines, you can shorten each individual line — and improve readability — considerably.

The best part is, this is nearly effortless. Honestly, a script could do the work that I just did, just as correctly and much more quickly. I know code formatting scripts exist for several languages, and I'd be very surprised if there wasn't one available for PHP.

Comment: +1 Nice work. And for actually making the effort.

Comment: Great, you won another scrollbar...

Answer (score 5):

Instead of posting a large wodge of code (even if it is well formatted, many people's attention spans quickly dry up, even mine), boil it down to a single atomic runnable snippet to allow other people to reproduce the problem you're experiencing.

Code such as the example you posted and even the nicely formatted version by [Popular Demand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67468/how-to-deliver-clean-code-to-so/67477#67477) will most likely go ignored because:

1. There's just too much to comprehend
2. It's dependant on other code or data we don't have access to or can't infer expected behaviour from

As a rule of thumb do a bit of work up front and this problem won't arise.

Comment: The content of my answer aside, I agree with this. Was just discussing it on another question yesterday, which you might find interesting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67365/why-isnt-there-a-copy-code-option-in-the-code-samples-block-closed (hm, it turned out to be a dupe.)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question - you presumably have an issue that you are working on, and want input for - but the root of the problem is that this is pretty bad code. No offense - I have old code lying around that looks the same. It's still bad.

If you start separating PHP and HTML, preparing and sanitizing variables in a code block, and build a coherent HTML block that you only fill stuff into and do the most basic control structures in, your code will automatically look much more pretty.