# Is it possible to add a function (button) to select a complete code block in a question?

Tags: feature-request, questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why isn't there a “copy code” option in the code samples block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67365/why-isnt-there-a-copy-code-option-in-the-code-samples-block)
>   [Shortcut for copying posted code from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow)

I often want to copy example code blocks from questions into my tools to execute it.

This requires some efforts to mark exactly the example code.

Any ideas to make this easier?