# What if there's a "copy" button near the code area?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortcut or button for copying posted code from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-or-button-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow)

What if we have a `copy` button near code area, so that single click will copy everything into clipboard?

The code area is sometimes too long and I need to scroll down, that's really wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

Every OS has a pretty easy copy-paste shortcut concept. I don't think this will imporove the site significantly.

Comment: Yeah but *selecting* can be a pain in bottom when the code block is small and your screen is small.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select text and Right click. Your browser will copy it for you.
```

Every browser have copy paste option. So there is no need to have additional development efforts to have copy buttons.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the other questions posted (copy-and-paste is sufficiently easy already), I'd argue that straight copying of the code from an answer is **not** usually the best course of action (even on high-quality answers).

You should read and understand the answer, using the code provided as a help to that. *Even* if the answer is *exactly* what you're looking for, chances are it will need to be adopted to your concrete project anyway. And in all this, the 1 second you take to select-and-copy will *certainly* not be the constraining factor.

Comment: The purpose (for me at least) is not to copy code from answers to use it; it's to copy code from questions to try it out so I can answer the question.