# Can Code Blocks Have "Copy Code" Buttons Attached to Them?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortcut or button for copying posted code from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-or-button-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow)

My normal routine when answering questions on SO very often involves compiling code from the question and possibly the answers.  This involves selecting the code from the code block, copying it and pasting it in to my IDE.

On a desktop with small code snippets and using a mouse, this is not terribly difficult. Just a click, drag and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>  Large code blocks become more involved especially when a mouse is not available.  Clicking, dragging and several keypresses can be a challenge on a laptop on a moving train (where I do much of my SO question answering) when the laptop is bouncing around.  Even on a desktop with a mouse I often make a mistake where I didn't drag quite right and have to do it several times before I get the right code in my IDE.

A copy-code button attached to each individual code block would make this process much simpler and less error-prone.  There would be one button attached next to each code block.  Clicking on this button would copy the entire contents of the code block to the clipboard in one click.

Consider an example ripped straight from the SO headlines today.  An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13993016/241536) was provided today with some code I'd like to try out.  The button might look like this:

[image]

Can we please have a copy code button?