# Is there a copy text link functionality available?

Tags: discussion, comments, markdown

#### TL;DR

In summary: I am looking for a (usability) method to add in the markdown, to provide a link to the user, which either:

- Selects the relevant text, or
- Selects the relevant text *and* copies it to the user's local clipboard

Does such a mechanism exist on SE?

---

With respect to this Meta question on SE.3D Printing, [Do we have Standardised Comments?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303), I have a list of standardised comments. Each standardised comment is shown in two formats:

1. As block quotes for readability
2. As code formatting, for ease of copy and paste (**C&P**)

As can be seen here

> [image: Example of C&P use]

The idea is such that, using the code formatted version of the comment,  people can select and copy it, and then paste into comments.

However, instead of the user having to perform two actions:

- wipe to select the code formatted text, (or triple clicking), and then;
- performing a copy (via keyboard, or menu, or right clicking for a contextual menu)

... is there any available functionality on SE, using a simple (additional markdown) link, to reduce the number of actions? Either by:

- Clicking to select
- Clicking to select *and* copy?

An example of the *Click to select* functionality can be seen on the Arduino forums, such as [Re: problems with stepper motor](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=14049.msg103893#msg103893). Note the `[select]` link in the image below:

[image: Example of 'select' link]

For example, a markdown construct sort of like this (I apologise for any poorly suggested syntax):

```
[[copyText]"This text will be selected and copied"]
```

which would render like this:

> [[copy](http://copy)] "This text will be selected and copied"

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're exactly asking for. You do know the script [auto review comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) exist?

Comment: Sorry. I have added a TL;DR, to hopefully clarify.

Comment: Ah yes, Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 has posted an answer referring to that StackApp on the meta post (at the bottom). Thanks. Yes, it is useful, but I was looking for an additional markdown solution/workaround, for people who don't want to install the stack app.

Comment: a bit related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-or-button-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow

Comment: @rene not a bit, it is almost dupe, since it's asking "only" for code blocks, while here it's more broad and asking to have such a feature in the markdown itself.

Comment: @rene - yes, that seems to be an option, but looking at the answers it doesn't appear to have been implemented yet, but also...

Comment: ...@ShadowWizard, yes, not only for code (although that would be a start) - I would like to have a option where you specify the selectable/copiable text in a markdown construct. I'll add an example to my post.

Comment: @Greenonline yeah, I know. BTW, your ping didn't work due to the "..." before. (I saw it now by chance when I noticed you edited.)