# What security concerns relate to having a "copy code" button?

Tags: discussion, security

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-or-button-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow#answer-71741) to a "copy code button" feature request states:

> I have learned that this functionality simply will not be implemented due to security concerns.

So what security concerns? I visit 'Codereview.stackexchange' and oftentimes copy & paste the code to run & modify it. What difference would a button make?

Comment: Remember when you used to get a "this page wants to access your Clipboard" warning message when using a similar button on other sites?

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog I've actually never seen that before

Answer (score 5):

> Clipboard is not secure, especially if you use IE browser, as it allows certain functions that allows a malicious page to run some javascript, that can read your stored clipboard data and then submit a form with that data.

You can read more about it’s security concerns [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33428/is-a-password-in-the-clipboard-vulnerable-to-attacks).

Or [here](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/688600/is-the-clipboard-secure/).

Comment: Not sure how much faith I have in the veracity of an article that begins _"This process uses Java instead of CSS"_

Comment: I don't buy the claim, either. If a "copy this code" button includes a trailing newline in the copied code, then so does a manual copy & paste. What's the difference? Instead of coddling, let's _educate_. The argument in that article is not very satisfying.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Thanks I have updated the links

Comment: Both new links are about _personal_ security: leaking passwords to other processes. That's not relevant for copying code. You'll also note that the answers on the Security.SE page say that although the clipboard is not secure, _that doesn't matter_ because any machine sufficiently compromised in such a manner is already much more screwed.

Comment: Is there a difference between highlighting some code, copying it (into the [clipboard?]) VS clicking a copy button (to copy in the [clipboard?])?