# New functionality to copy code to the clipboard for "Stack Overflow" in Spanish

Tags: discussion, feature-request

## New functionality to copy code to clipboard

I made an [approach in Meta Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4558/nueva-funcionalidad-para-copiar-c%c3%b3digo-fuente-al-portapapeles) about the possibility of implementing a new feature, that is, copy code through a button.

I decided to translate it into English to share it here.

> I have already noted that such functionality is already available in **Stack Overflow** in English, but is not yet available in the Spanish version.

#### Here I share the translated version

---

I wish that a function that allows code fragments to be copied to the **clipboard** could be implemented in **Stack Overflow**; published in the questions and/or answers. That is, instead of being done on a PC, Tablet_ or Smartphone_ in a way similar to this:

[image: Vista Previa]

Simply press a *button* to allow the same action described above. That is, something similar to the following example:

[image: Vista Previa]

So, my motivation on this issue is to make it easier for people (including me) to ask questions and answers to copy the code safely and test them on site quickly, in addition to reducing the famous human errors, which is when We select code snippets, especially if they are too long.

#### These would be the questions for a possible proposal:

- What possibilities exist or to whom should we go to propose the implementation of the function described above?
- And in case it is not possible, what would be the possible reason?
- And finally, taking into account all the above, would you agree that this new feature should be implemented at **Stack Overflow**?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-or-button-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow.

Comment: I use https://github.com/MrMino/StackCtrlC. Since then I'm perfectly happy.

Comment: Although there's no doubt it's a duplicate, the original question is from ...2009. And we still don't have it :)

Comment: @Pikoh Yes, that's the sad part, but it's also true that asking again and again for it would not make it more likely, likely.