# Extra newline risks running unwanted commands

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Triple-clicking on a code block like the ones [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153863/420478) highlight the line with an additional newline at the end. When the user copies and pastes it into the terminal the extra newline results in the command being executed (in bash shell, your experience may vary depending on shell). If it's a command that deletes files this can result in a complete disaster.

I tested it on other websites and they sometimes have the same behavior, so it might be some innate behavior of triple-click and the relevant HTML elements.

Still, if there is a way to prevent this behavior I'm sure it would help someone out in the future.

Comment: What terminal do you have? I have Konsole (default KDE) and no matter how many times I click and coipy/pase the command is never run until I press enter.

Comment: Eh, I think it is useless "bug" that apparently occurs only on certain computers, and even if you have the problem there is ***a beyond-easy solution:*** Press and hold, then highlight it by moving your cursor backwards across the line without selecting the extra  line! Easy!

Comment: It seems this a feature of the Gnome terminal, there are a few work around here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/377259/stop-terminal-auto-executing-when-pasting-a-command

Comment: This is part of Windows' CMD's behavior, too, but I don't think it's caused by that newline. There are plenty of sources where a triple click will highlight the line, as well as some whitespace after it.

Comment: The bofh answer to this would be 'don't copy and paste code' . My preferred windows ssh tool - mobaxterm will show you what you pasted before you run it, so I guess it's enough of a problem for someone to mitigate

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with Stack Exchange itself. There are many commands that are destructive and which are posted here. It's not up to this site to censor or police the commands—especially with respect to some obscure issue. Even regardless of the triple-click issue, somebody could still copy and paste the command itself—and still have the same result. But that's their issue, not this site's. This reads like "`rm` is dangerous, we should automatically post code that says `r_` instead, or use a spoiler …"

Comment: @MarkKirby bash.

 
@ mindstormsboi Yes, it has a very easy workaround. If you remember.

 
@ JourneymanGeek Not copying and pasting risks typos. That's a cool feature, interesting.

 
@ JasonBassford The site does not have a legal responsibility to censor or police commands, correct. This is just a feature request to help others (and helping others is what Stackoverflow is all about).

Comment: Solution would be a [button to copy code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-or-button-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow), however it still doesn't exist.

Comment: @Almenon Bash is the shell you are interacting with but what is responsible for this behaviour is the terminal emulator you are using, default on most desktops is the Gnome terminal

Comment: @Almenon Nobody is saying that you shouldn't copy & paste. But maybe instead of pasting a line of shell code directly into the terminal, consider pasting it into your editor first. Another option is to start the `cat` command, so anything you paste (or type) just gets echoed back to you.

Answer (score 2):

How should the system prevent such behavior? 
When you triple click and copy, what you get is plain text, 
you don't *copy* anything that have been programmed to generate these text. 
If what you're asking for is to make the system remove any newlines the OP put in the end of the code, well, there *are* times the newlines are intentional.

This probably goes without saying, but you can avoid the extra lines by clicking and dragging your cursor over the text until the desired block is highlighted.